# Get hacked Joomla back on the rails

Tags: php, joomla

I have an old joomla installation which was hacked. All I know for now only index.php was changed and they messed with my user accounts. I downloaded index.php from the current version but at one point it calls `$app->dispatch();` which requires a component name parameter in my version. Does anyone know what parameter this should be? I tried: null, 'home', 'application',...

Also I'm planning on updating to the newest version later, however I can't seem to find my current version number. I found somewhere that it is displayed in the admin pages but I can't access them yet. Can I find it in the code files somewhere?

**EDIT:** The index.php from version 1.5.22 worked. Apparently the correct version was 1.5.3. Does anyone know what else I should check that might have been hacked/messed with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get a copy of the version you used?

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2221953

> You can go to the joomla project on
>   joomlacode.org, then select the search
>   tab. From there you type in "1.0.10"
>   and select Releases to search in. You
>   should get some results. Click on the
>   one you are searching for, the files
>   can be found on the files tab, this
>   time the tab is on a blue bar (more to
>   the bottom of the screen).

Although I'd recommend upgrading completely, to stop being re-hacked again.

====== Answer to second question

How big is the site? Usually if it's just a link spamming attack a quick once over will suffice.

The next issue is that you need to patch the hole that caused the problem, in this case upgrading to the latest Joomla (1.6 - I believe) is the first port of call.

Have you modifed the Joomla system in such a way that the hack could have been opened up by you?

My advice, reset the admin passwords and upgrade Joomla.

Very difficult to say anything else without seeing what the "hack" was.

Comment: This search "solution" (from 2008) doesn't work anymore. All code prior to version 1.5 has been removed from that website...

Comment: What version are you looking for? http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseView&release_id=6828 There is 1.0 it's not hard to find the other versions.

Comment: I still don't know what my current version number is. Can I find it in the code files somewhere?

Comment: Bottom of each page in the admin.

Comment: This part has been resolved. I knew it was visible there somewhere, however not on the login page and since I was hacked I couldn't logon...

Comment: @koen hack is a pretty borad term, how could anyone know you couldnt log in?

Comment: It was kinda in my initial post, 2nd paragraph (maybe not clear enough): "I found somewhere that it is displayed in the admin pages but I can't access them yet. Can I find it in the code files somewhere?"

Comment: @koen, I've tried now to answer your question. I do hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll first try to upgrade to 1.5.22 which is the last version from 1.5. That should be easy and is likely to fix the exploit they used. Can't go to 1.6 yet since it requires a newer MySql version than what my hosting provider offers. Can't really put a name on the hack. I only know they replaced the home page with something "Turkish Islamitic". It appears to be a quite typical hack (replacing index.php and changing admin account name and passwords - they didn't even touch the other accounts).

Answer (score 2):

I had to clean out a hacked Joomla install recently. My tip is to grep all the files base64_decode: some hacks consist of decoding a huge string that emits php.

find ./ | xargs grep base64_decode

The hack looked like this: error_reporting(0);eval(base64_decode('JGxMOXdGMWFZNHpY.....

This particular piece of code detected googlebot and other crawlers, and then emitted a list of spam links heavy on viagra. If a normal user agent string was used it showed a normal site. I had to use a firefox extension that changes the user agent to debug this.

The next step would be getting rid of the exploit and then either patching Joomla and waiting for the next exploit or switching to something more secure, like static html or a well-maintained CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Joomla has really nice documentation on how to recover from a hack. http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist_7. As Pino mentioned, it is critical that you are always on the latest version to minimize your exposure to security exploits.

Comment: I read this article in the past. Unfortunately everything is so Linux server focussed while we are on a Windows machine so most of these checklists simply don't apply or the "security fix" works differently...

Comment: Other than the HTACCESS and CHMOD parts of that document, everything applies regardless of server technology.